# Google Dataflow custom metrics not showing on Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to get a deeper view on my dataflow jobs by measuring parts of it using `Metrics.counter` & `Metrics.gauge` but I cannot find them on Stackdriver.

I have a premium Stackdriver account and I can see those counters under the Custom Counters section on the Dataflow UI.

I can see `droppedDueToLateness` 'custom' counter though on Stackdriver [that seems to be created via `Metrics.counter` as well](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/29859eb54d05b96a9db477e7bb04537510273bd2/runners/core-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java#L102)...

Aside from that, there's something that could be helpful that is that when I navigate https://app.google.stackdriver.com/services/dataflow the message I get is this:
"You do not have any resources of this type being monitored by Stackdriver." and that's weird as well. As if our Cloud Dataflow wasn't properly connected to Stackdriver, but, on the other hand. Some metrics are displayed and can be monitored such as System Lag, Watermark age, Elapsed time, Element count, etc...

What am I missing?

Regards

Comment: Hi Carlos - Thanks for posting here :)

Let's first double check your Stackdriver Account.  Do you have only one?
Can you check that the GCP project in which you are running your Dataflow is the GCP project listed under your Stackdriver Account settings (accessed via "Account settings" under the project dropdown on the Stackdriver page)?

Comment: Are you adhering to the [custom metric naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details#label_names)? I had the same problem as you, and this was the reason.

Comment: Also, note that Dataflow does not currently support Gauge metrics. See: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/#cap-full-what

Comment: Hi @Andrea I've checked and the Stackdriver account is the same as the GCP one where the dataflow is running.

Comment: @Robbe I don't think I fully understood that docs. The [Metrics.counter](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/) receives the class and the metric name. I'm using, for example, a class of my package and "SubmittedWindows" as the name, are those valid ones?

Comment: @ScottWegner Thanks! Yeah, I checked it and I'm using both counters and gauges, but none of them appear...

Comment: I create a metric with `Metrics.counter('namespace', 'name')`. This shows up in Stackdriver as _custom.googleapis.com/dataflow/name_, so 'name' should adhere to the _metric label name_ rules in the linked document. The 'namespace' doesn't seem to be used. The whole metric documentation is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Ok @Robbe that was it!! I was using a colon as part of the name and it was silently not working... Thanks a lot!! If you post this as a solution I'll accept it straight away. Thanks

Comment: And BTW, is it possible to add 'labels' to those metrics? To distinguish different properties of the same metric? (i.e. I have a counter of messages and I want to aggregate by the different 'origins' of those messages) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Custom metric naming conventions**

When defining custom metrics in Dataflow, you have to adhere to the [custom metric naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details#label_names), or they won't show up in Stackdriver.

Relevant snippet:

> You must adhere to the following spelling rules for metric label
> names:
>
> - You can use upper and lower-case letters, digits, underscores (_) in
>   the names.
> - You can start names with a letter or digit.
> - The maximum length of a metric label name is 100 characters.

If you create a metric with

```
Metrics.counter('namespace', 'name')
```

The metric shows up in stackdriver as *custom.googleapis.com/dataflow/name*, so 'name' should adhere to the rules mentioned above. The namespace does not seem to be used by Stackdriver.

**Additional: labels**

It doesn't seem possible to add labels to the metrics when defined this way. However, the full description of each time series of a metric is a string with the format

```
'name' job_name job_id transform
```

So you can aggregate by these 4 properties (+ region and project).

Comment: Thanks! in my case, I had a (white)space in the name

Comment: Is it possible to log custom metrics/counter values from a java streaming beam pipeline to cloud logging?